# Using nested if functions

Tags: excel, function, nested

I am new to using nested if functions in excel. I would like to find out what the correct functions for my excel spreadsheet.

1. if the pH is <7.35 and the PaCO2 is  >6.00, or if the WOB is documented as a yes. I would like to the cell to return a yes response and if not the cell should return a no response.
2. if 6 columns in my spreadsheet all have yes responses eg a1,b1,c1,d1,e1,f1, i would like the cell in the 7th column i.e. g1 to return a yes response. however if any cell in a1,b1,c1,d1,e1,f1 has either a no , unknown or blank response , g1 should return a no response.

I would be grateful if someone could help me with this by tomorrow - as it is for a work project. Thank you

Comment: 1. If(OR(And(pHcell<7.35,PaCO2cell>6.00), WOBcell="Yes"),"Yes","No response")

Comment: 2. If(Countif(A1:F1,"Yes")=6,"YES","No response")

Comment: I upvote VBA Pete's countif idea due to its simplicity. Also, if the number of columns were to be expanded, linking the "6" to a cell will make the formula modular.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I also have these two more questions: 1) If I had two columns not adjacent to each other e.g. a1 and c1. If a1 and c1 had dates entered i.e. not blank, what function would I use to put a yes response in column d1, but also put in a no response in d1 if either a1 or c1 were blank. 2) if i had four columns e.g. a1 is a date for event 1, b1 is a time for event 1, c1 is a date for event 2 and d1 is a time for event 2. How can i calculate whether event 2 happened less than or equal to 20 minutes from event 1. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Lets assume question 1 in on one sheet and question 2 is on another for sake of example. Simply transpose to your case:

If pH is in column A, PaCO2 is in column B, and WOB is in column C, your formula would look like this `=IF(OR(AND(A1<7.35,B1>6),C1="YES"),"YES","NO")` and paste this in the desired column on row 1. You can copy this down for all applicable rows.

For your second enquiry, I wouldn't use a nested if statement as it restricts you to only the 6 cells you have listed. The following formula will work for as many cells as you like `=IFERROR(INDEX(A1:F1,MATCH("NO",A1:F1,0)),"YES")`. In this case, you would simply expand your column set for both instances of `A1:F1`

The nested If statements would look like this (if you choose to go that direction): `=IF(A1="NO","NO",IF(B1="NO","NO",IF(C1="NO","NO",IF(D1="NO","NO",IF(E1="NO","NO",IF(F1="NO","NO","YES"))))))`

Comment: Thank you for your help. 

I also have these two more questions: 

1) If I had two columns not adjacent to each other e.g. a1 and c1. If a1 and c1 had dates entered i.e. not blank, what function would I use to put a yes response in column d1, but also put in a no response in d1 if either a1 or c1 were blank. 

2) if i had four columns e.g. a1 is a date for event 1, b1 is a time for event 1, c1 is a date for event 2 and d1 is a time for event 2. How can i calculate whether event 2 happened less than or equal to 20 minutes from event 1. 

Thank you

Comment: For question 1, use the nested if statement above however add `ISNUMBER` in the logical test. It will return FALSE if the cell is a string or is blank.

Comment: For question 2, the following will work: `=IF(SUM(C1:D1)-(20/(60*24))>SUM(A1:B1),"MORE","LESS")`. if you want to add cells between the dates and times, replace `SUM(A1:B1)` with `(A1+B1)`. don't forget the brackets.